# Gain of essence reavers cdr

Tags: league-of-legends

This is the description of essence reaver:

> +65 Attack Damage
>   +20% Critical Strike Chance
>
> UNIQUE Passive: +10% Cooldown Reduction.
>   UNIQUE Passive: Gain
>   increasingly more Cooldown Reduction from Critical Strike Chance
>   provided by other sources (maximum +20% additional Cooldown Reduction
>   at 30% Critical Strike Chance).
>   UNIQUE Passive: Critical strikes restore 3% of your maximum Mana pool.

I wanted to know, if the critical chance of the item itself (20%) is getting involved here as well. When I for instance have 10% critical chance through runes and would buy essence reaver, would I gain 30% cdr instantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No my friend it does not, you can read it [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Essence_Reaver)

## you can see that they specify

"Gain additional Cooldown Reduction depending on Critical Strike chance ***from other sources***."

**EDIT**: Sometimes all we need is to read things carefully. :)